# Returning a pointer to an object from a list

Tags: c++, list, pointers, reference

I have a list of objects in a class FutureEvent where I want to be able to go something like futureEvents.getNextEvent(). This is currently what I have which works however because of the New call I think this is the cause of my major memory leak. Any help would be greatly appreciated. How else can I return the pointer to the next event. Thanks

```
EVENT* FutureEvent::getNextEvent()
{
EVENT* nextEvent = new EVENT;
*nextEvent = futureEvents.front();
futureEvents.pop_front();
return nextEvent;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't `delete` the result of this function anywhere, this is certainly the cause of a memory leak.

Possible solutions include:

1. **Returning by value**

   With this approach you don't even need to use dynamic allocation (i.e. `new`). You only use automatic objects, so you don't need to clean up: the memory they use is automatically released and any destructors are called automatically.

   ```
   EVENT FutureEvent::getNextEvent() {
       EVENT nextEvent = futureEvents.front();
       futureEvents.pop_front();
       return nextEvent;
   }
   ```
2. **Using a smart pointer**

   This approach still uses dynamic allocation, but it delegates to a class that can take care of the cleanup automatically.

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<EVENT> FutureEvent::getNextEvent() {
       std::unique_ptr<EVENT> nextEvent(new EVENT(futureEvents.front()));
       futureEvents.pop_front();
       return nextEvent;
   }
   ```

   If your compiler doesn't support `std::unique_ptr` you can use one of the smart pointers in Boost, like `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: You could also have a EVENT * in the method parameters, which helps organize the code. Whoever calls the method needs to supply the data structure to store the result, which means he allocates the memory and is responsible for releasing it.

Comment: Thanks very much passing by value solved my problems. Greatly appreciated

Comment: According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/pop_front/, calling pop_front will call the destructor on the element being remove. Keeping access to the object after this point could cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @dtyler: first of all cplusplus.com is a bad reference as it contains factual errors and bad examples in some places. But the important thing to note is that in all three snippets (the original, and the two I posted) the object being returned is different one from the one in `futureEvents`. It's a copy (the copy is made with the assignment in the original, and with the copy constructor in my examples).

Comment: Since you explicitly mention that your solution 1 needs a copy constructor: so does OP’s code (*and* your second example). So the mention is misleading.